# html2canvas downloading problem with android phones

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript

So I made a script that captures a div of my website and it starts downloading automatically.

The problem is that it only works on PC. I tried with a bunch of android phones and the picture does not download and gives an error that it can not be downloaded. what should I do for this situation?

The code :

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById("ssss"), {
  useCORS: true
    }).then(function (canvas) {
  var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = imageURL;
  a.download = imageURL;
  a.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got the answer myself after dealing with the problem for hours I realized that all I needed to do was to add a few lines.

new Code :

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("image-div-id"), {
        imageTimeout: 15000, //newline
        scale:3, //newline
        useCORS: true
}).then(function (canvas) {
  var imageURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = imageURL;
  a.download = "letter.jpg";
  a.click();
```